# Matrix normalization over multiple runs, what does this code do?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matrix

I have several numpy matrices collected over some time. I now want to visualize these matrices and explore visual similarities among them. The matrices contain small numbers from 0.0 to 1.0.

To compare them, I want to ensure that the same "areas" get colored with the same color, e.g. that 0.01 to 0.02 always is red, and 0.02 to 0.03 always is green. I have two question:

I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552641/plotting-a-2d-matrix-in-python-code-and-most-useful-visualization) which has this code snippet:

```
a = np.random.normal(0.0,0.5,size=(5000,10))**2
a = a/np.sum(a,axis=1)[:,None]  # Normalize

plt.pcolor(a)
```

What is the effect of the second line, precisely the `[:,None]` statement. I tried normalizing a matrix by:

```
max_a = a/10# Normalize
print(max_a.shape)
plt.pcolor(max_a)
```

but there is not much visual difference compared to the visualization for the unnormalized matrix. When I then add the `[:,None]` statement I get an error

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

which is expected since the shape now is `10,1,10`. I therefor want to know what the brackets do and how to read the statement.

Secondly, and related, I want to make sure that I can visual compare the matrices. I therefor want to fix the "colorization", e.g. the ranges when a color is green or red, so that I do not end up with 0 to 0.1 as green in plot A and with 0 to 0.1 as red in plot B. How can I fix the "translation" from floats to colors? Do I have to normalize each matrix with a same constant, e.g. 10? Or do I normalize them with an unique value -- do I even need normalization here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[:,None]` adds new axis so you'll be able to divide sum of all columns in each row - it is the same as using `np.sum(a,axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]` - when you sum all columns with `np.sum(a,axis=1)` you'll get 1d array with shape `(5000)`, but to be able to normalize your matrix with summed columns you need 2d array with shape `(5000,1)`, that's why new axis is needed.

You can have fixed colors by fixing scale of your colormap: `plt.pcolor(max_a,vmin=0,vmax=1)`

adding [discrete colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14777392/3809172) might also help:

```py
from pylab import cm

cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet', 10)  
plt.pcolor(a,cmap=cmap,vmin=0,vmax=1)
plt.colorbar()
```